# How to wisely choose image resolution based on its container size?

Tags: html, image, performance, web, compression

Given:

1. I have a container of 64px * 64px which is used to display an image
2. I have an image of a very high resolution (5000px * 5000px)

**What resolution would be optimal for the image?**

Assuming that website will not be zoomed and I want image to look perfect on all possible devices.

P.S.
My assumption is that 64px * 64px is not a suitable resolution for image because there are devices with pixel ratio > 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your container is of size 64*64 px then you should look for the same aspect ratio in this case it's 1x1. When you've got the aspect ratio you should crop your images to the same size. Usually you would provide several images with different aspect ratios to your website and let the user's browser figure out which one is the best. Desktops and mobiles have different aspect ratios, for my desktop websites I tend to use 4x3 aspect ratio images with resolution up to 1600x1000 sometimes even up to 1920x1200 and for mobile I'd use 3x4 aspect with resolution up to 800x1200. In production you don't as big resolutions as 5000x5000 cause there is really no need for it, also prior to deploy you should optimize your images for web to make their file size smaller - mainly use .jpg and .svg extensions for that.
Hopefully that clears some things up.